# select en laravel entre tablas muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Para seleccionar columnas especificas en laravel mediante select por obligación debes traer el id y las fk para que se puedan relacionar las tuplas, pero cuando quiero hacer un **->select()** entre una relación mucho a mucho no me funciona ya que en medio *hay una tabla pivote y supongo que igual debes cargar sus pk y fk.* como se suele hacer en relaciones de otras cardinalidades.

¿Como debo poner las fk y pk de la tabla pivote en el select para poder traer campos específicos?

Supongamos que tenemos una notificacion que está relacionada con usuarios de muchos a muchos, y esa notificación puede tener N comentarios relacionados a una notificación (una notificación puede tener N comentarios, un comentario sólo puede estar en una notificación)

por ejemplo

```
 $comentarios = Comentario::select('id','texto','users_fk','notificaciones_fk','created_at','updated_at')
                             ->where('notificaciones_fk', $request->notificacion_id)
                             ->where('activo', 1)
                             ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                             ->with(['notificacion.users' => function($query){
                                $query->with('perfil');
// En este $query aplicar un select para traer campos específicos de usuarios, 
// pero al haber una tabla pivote de por medio, como debo especificar la id y las fk 
// de la tabla pivote? Independientemente de que utilice select() o 
// cargue con eager loading los atributos :id,atributo,atributo_fk debo
// especificar los primary y foreign para que se pueda llevar a cabo la
// consulta

                             }])
                             ->paginate($perPage);
```

O en su defecto, hay alguna forma de quitar u ocultar columnas de las consultas que no sea agregar campos en la propiedad $hidden del modelo?

Answer (score 0):

La tabla pivote se puede obviar de definir sus pk y fk, pero es necesario en las tablas que no son pivote al hacer el select definir previamente el nombre de la tabla.

```
nombredelatabla.propiedad
```